# How to use forward method in spring web flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to forward a request to a different internal endpoint from a WebFlux RestContoller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/connection-success", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Mono<String> connectionSuccess(@RequestParam("status") String status,
                                          @RequestParam("message") String message) {
        ......
        return Mono.just("forward:/connections");
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/connections", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Mono<String> getConnections(Authentication authentication,
                                   Model model,
                                   WebSession webSession) {
       .......
       return Mono.just("customer/connection");
}
```

But when I did call connection-success then This type of error show

```
2022-06-20 10:18:05.383 ERROR lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1 - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler#error - [de6316a]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/customer/connection-success?status=0&message=Connection%20updated%20successfully"
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/customer/connections'.
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolutionResultHandler.lambda$resolveViews$3(ViewResolutionResultHandler.java:278) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.dft.ra.controller.CustomerController#connectionSuccess(String, String) [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerWebExchangeContextFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/customer/connection-success?status=0&message=Connection%20updated%20successfully" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolutionResultHandler.lambda$resolveViews$3(ViewResolutionResultHandler.java:278) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this approach, using redirect:

Approach 1 :
Sample :

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("hi")
    @ResponseBody
    public Mono<String> hi() {
        return Mono.just("hi");
    }

    @GetMapping("hiRedirect")
    public Mono<String> hiRedirect() {
        return Mono.just("redirect:/hi");
    }

}
```

Ref : https://devdojo.com/ketonemaniac/spring-webflux-redirects

Approach 2 :

Redirecting with Controller MVC good-old approach:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.net.URI;

@RestController
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public Mono<Void> indexController(ServerHttpResponse response) {
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT);
        response.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("/api/v1"));
        return response.setComplete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for Answering this question but I can't use redirect method in my app. I have to preserve my parameters and use forward method.